Meaning of the symbol $\rlap{\oplus}\otimes$



I found this cool wheel symbol on youtube.
What is this symbol and what is it for?
I recognize some algebraic geometry words.

I've never seen it before so it's not standard enough to have been part of my education. But any author can introduce and use whatever symbols they want in their own papers. So it's probably introduced in the paper that youtube video references.

it is like one of the pictograms from the Linear B script - you can make it with \BPwheel if you have the linearb package installed, but it won't work on mse. But it isn't identical, so probably the person who made that diagram was using a different package.
